# Is there a generalization of std::bitset for two-bit values?

Tags: c++

Suppose I am a genome scientist trying to store extremely long strings of characters, each of which represents two bits of information (i.e. each element is either G, A, T, or C).  Because the strings are incredibly long, I need to be able to store a string of length N in precisely 2N bits (or rather, N/4 bytes).

With that motivation in mind, I am looking for a generalization of `std::bitset` (or `boost::dynamic_bitset<>`) that works on two-bit values instead of single-bit values.  I want to store `N` such two-bit values, each of which can be 0, 1, 2, or 3.  I need the data packed as closely as possible in memory, so `vector<char>` will not work (as it wastes a factor of 4 of memory).

What is the best way to achieve my goal?  One option is to wrap the existing bitset templates with customized `operator[]`, iterators, etc., but I'd prefer to use an existing library if at all possible.

Comment: Hmm, what's actually wrong for you with `std::bitset<2>`?!? No way to use less than an `uint8_t` IMHO. No doubts that `std::bitset` will use this as underlying type for decent implementations?

Comment: What makes you think `bitset<N>` consists of `N bool`s?

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. `TheClass<5, 2> c; c[0] = 0; c[1] = 1; c[2] = 2; c[3] = 3; /* WRONG c[4] = 4 */` I'm interested in appliances though.

Comment: @milleniumbug Ehh, what?!? Sarcasm?

Comment: @Praetorian I do not understand your question.  `bitset<N>` stores `N` bits.  I want to store `N` two-bits values, each of which can be 0, 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `std::bitset<2>` only stores a single two-bit value.  I want a data structure that packs `N` of them together, just as `bitset` does for single bits.

Comment: @JimGarrison Ok, I understand your question now. You should edit and add the description in your comment to the question. Currently it seems like you're asking for `bitset<2>`, which you seem to think is an array of 2 `bool`

Comment: As for your question, I think there probably isn't (but I would like to be proven wrong). Fortunately, isn't not that complicated to write (wrap an array of `char`s or `std::vector<char>`, do the bit-fiddling yourself, and provide the interface)

Comment: I don't know of any existing libraries, but you should be able to make `bitset<2N>` work. You could provide an interface that does the necessary index translation.

Comment: @JimGarrison `std::bitset<>` actually already generalizes an abstraction for 2^N bit values, known at compile time? Did you ask for  run time optimization or what? Clarify this question, it's unclear!

Comment: Meant s.th like `std::array<std::bitset<2>,N>`??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The question was clear enough for me, but here you go: such class `TheClass<X, B>`, that value of it's type stores X B-bit values in (X*B/8)+1 bytes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sure, I want an interface similar to `std::array<std::bitset<2>, N>`, but that itself will not work because each element of the array will use at least one byte to represent the bitset, even though only two bits are actually used.  I need the data packed as closely as possible in memory.

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm not sure but may be some optimizing  de-/serialization libraries like e.g. [google-protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) could be suitable for optimizing your case.

Comment: @JimGarrison _'Is there an existing library available ...'_ Just to remind you, asking for 3rd party resources is OT.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."  I am not asking for opinions -- I am just trying to find any existing library that works!

Comment: @JimGarrison And anyway I gave you a link that might convey a viable solution. There's no c++ standard solution i could think about, meeting your stated requirements!

Comment: '**or** find' not '**and** find' -- lack of opinions is not relevant.  Asking 'how do I do X' is ok, asking 'find me a library that does X' is not.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ protocol buffers does not implement what I am asking for.  Nonetheless I foresee no difficulty implementing a solution in standard C++98.

Comment: @JimGarrison _'protocol buffers does not implement ...'_ Sure? It's pretty good at packing stuff to the minimal necessary required space/representation, if done right. Sorry I can't give more advice. Another option is you're going to implement something appropriate yourself (OCTET parsing, and storing the raw way :P ...)

Answer (score 2):

`std::bitset<>` is fixed length and you probably do not want that.

I think you should go ahead and wrap `std::vector<bool>`.

Note that `std::vector<bool>` *is* optimised for space, but has the benefit that it is dynamic in size.
Presumably you need to read the genome of arbitrary length on from somewhere.

Have a think about whether you need much of an API to access it; you might only need a couple of methods.

@Jefffrey's answer already covers the relevant code, if for `bitset<>`.

[ I am not familiar with `boost::dynamic_bitset<>` and what it might give over `vector`.]

One further thought is whether it might be convenient for you to work with quads of letters, a quad nicely filling a char in space.

```
class Genome
{
public:
    enum class Letter {A,C,G,T};
    Genome(const std::string& source)
    {
        code_.resize(source.size() * 2);
        for (unsigned index = 0; index != source.size(); ++index)
        {
            char text = source[index];
            Letter letter = textToLetter(text);
            set(index, letter);
        }
    }  
    static Letter textToLetter(char text)
    {
        // Or search through the array `letterText`.
        // Or come up with a neat but unintelligible one liner ...
        Letter letter = Letter::A;
        switch (text)
        {
        case 'A':
            letter = Letter::A;
            break;
        case 'C':
            letter = Letter::C;
            break;
        case 'G':
            letter = Letter::G;
            break;
        case 'T':
            letter = Letter::T;
            break;
        default:
            // Invalid - handle error.
            break;
        }
        return letter;
    }
    static char letterToText(Letter l) 
    {
        return letterText[(unsigned)l];
    }
    // Add bounds checking
    Letter get(unsigned index) const
    {
        unsigned distance = index * 2;
        char numeric = code_[distance] + code_[distance + 1] * 2;
        return Letter(numeric);
    }
    // Add bounds checking
    void set(unsigned index, Letter value)
    {
        unsigned distance = index * 2;
        bool low = (unsigned)value & 1;
        bool high = (bool)((unsigned)value & 2);
        code_[distance] = low;
        code_[distance + 1]  = high;
    }
    unsigned size()
    {
        return code_.size() / 2;
    }
    // Extend by numLetters, initially set to 'A'
    void extend(unsigned numLetters)
    {
        code_.resize(code_.size() + numLetters * 2);
    }
private:

    static char letterText[4];
    std::vector<bool> code_;
};

char Genome::letterText [4] = { 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T' };

int main()
{
    Genome g("GATT");
    g.extend(3);
    g.set(5, Genome::Letter::C);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i != g.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << Genome::letterToText(g.get(i));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `boost::dynamic_bitset` has no tangible benefit over `std::vector<bool>`, it's just to satisfy people who can't live with a Boolean vector named `std::vector<bool>`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices.

Given:

```
enum class nucleobase { a, c, g, t };
```

You have two choices. You can:

- use a single `std::bitset` and play with indexing
- use `std::bitset` in combination with another container

For the first, you can just define a couple of functions that target the correct number of bits per set/get:

```
template<std::size_t N>
void set(std::bitset<N>& bits, std::size_t i, nucleobase x) {
    switch (x) {
        case nucleobase::a: bits.set(i * 2, 0); bits.set(i * 2 + 1, 0); break;
        case nucleobase::c: bits.set(i * 2, 0); bits.set(i * 2 + 1, 1); break;
        case nucleobase::g: bits.set(i * 2, 1); bits.set(i * 2 + 1, 0); break;
        case nucleobase::t: bits.set(i * 2, 1); bits.set(i * 2 + 1, 1); break;
    }
}

template<std::size_t N>
nucleobase get(const std::bitset<N>& bits, std::size_t i) {
    if (!bits[i * 2])
        if (!bits[i * 2 + 1]) return nucleobase::a;
        else                  return nucleobase::c;
    else
        if (!bits[i * 2 + 1]) return nucleobase::g;
        else                  return nucleobase::t;
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e74946d722fe0de)

The above is just an example and a terrible one (it's almost 4AM here and I really need to sleep).

For the second you just need to map alleles and bits:

```
bit_pair bits_for(nucleobase x) {
    switch (x) {
        case nucleobase::a: return bit_pair("00"); break;
        case nucleobase::c: return bit_pair("10"); break;
        case nucleobase::g: return bit_pair("01"); break;
        case nucleobase::t: return bit_pair("11"); break;
    }
}

nucleobase nucleobase_for(bit_pair x) {
    switch (x.to_ulong()) {
        case 0: return nucleobase::a; break;
        case 1: return nucleobase::c; break;
        case 2: return nucleobase::g; break;
        case 3: return nucleobase::t; break;
        default: return nucleobase::a; break; // just for the warning
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/334e92e5634c4dea)

Of course if you need runtime length you can just use `boost::dynamic_bitset` and `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use for fixed-length k-mers.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ostream>

enum class nucleotide { A, C, G, T };

inline std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& pOut, nucleotide pNt)
{
    switch (pNt) {
        case nucleotide::A: pOut << 'A'; break;
        case nucleotide::C: pOut << 'C'; break;
        case nucleotide::G: pOut << 'G'; break;
        case nucleotide::T: pOut << 'T'; break;
    }
    return pOut;
}

class kmer_base;

class nucleotide_proxy {
public:
    operator nucleotide() const {
        return nucleotide((*mWord >> (mPosition * 2)) & 3);
    };

    nucleotide_proxy& operator=(nucleotide pNt) {
        uint64_t word = *mWord;
        word &= ~(uint64_t(3) << (mPosition*2));
        word |= uint64_t(pNt) << (mPosition*2);
        *mWord = word;

        return *this;
    };

private:
    friend class kmer_base;

    nucleotide_proxy(uint64_t* pWord, uint8_t pPosition)
        : mWord(pWord), mPosition(pPosition)
    {
    }

    uint64_t* mWord;
    uint8_t mPosition;
};


class kmer_base {
protected:
    nucleotide_proxy access(uint64_t* pWord, size_t pPosition)
    {
        return nucleotide_proxy(pWord + (pPosition / 32), (pPosition & 31));
    }

    const nucleotide_proxy access(uint64_t* pWord, size_t pPosition) const
    {
        return nucleotide_proxy(pWord + (pPosition / 32), (pPosition & 31));
    }
};


template<int K>
class kmer : public kmer_base
{
    enum { Words = (K + 31) / 32 };
public:
    nucleotide_proxy operator[](size_t pOutdex) {
        return access(mWords, pOutdex);
    }

    const nucleotide_proxy operator[](size_t pOutdex) const {
        return access(mWords, pOutdex);
    }

private:
    uint64_t mWords[Words];
};
```

Extending this to dynamic-length k-mere is left as an exercise; it's pretty easy once you have `nucleotide_proxy` at your disposal. Implementing the reverse complement operator efficiently is also left as an exercise.